# Android Text Watcher Calculation missing

Tags: android

I have a three EditText elements.I want to make a calculation based on first two edittext values to stored in thired edit text field.

but the calculations going wrongly always. whenever i clear the typed values from secound edit text the calculation not working proply.

```
 public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int a, int b, int c) {
            try{
                a=Integer.parseInt(totamt.getText().toString().trim());
                b=Integer.parseInt(expenses.getText().toString().trim());
                c=Integer.parseInt(handover_amt.getText().toString().trim());
                int d = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(a)) - Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(b)) - Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(c));
                balance_amt.setText(String.valueOf(d));

                int myOB =  Integer.parseInt(et_overall_balance.getText().toString().trim());
                int OverallBalance = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(myOB)) - Integer.parseInt(handover_amt.getText().toString().trim());
                et_overall_balance.setText(String.valueOf(OverallBalance));
                System.out.println(OverallBalance);

            }catch(NumberFormatException numberEx)
            {
                System.out.println(numberEx);
            }

        }
```

Comment: What you want to display in third edittext?

Comment: edittext3=edittext1-edittext2. user will be enter the values in edittext2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code

```
edittext2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if (edittext1.getText().toString().trim() != null && !edittext1.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                    if (edittext2.getText().toString().trim() != null && !edittext2.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                        edittext3.setText("" + (Double.parseDouble(edittext1.getText().toString().trim()) - Double.parseDouble(edittext2.getText().toString().trim())));
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(activity, "Please enter value in edittext 2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "Please enter value in edittext 1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: i tried your code but same problem . the problem is E.g for `EDITTEXT1=5000 ;` `EDITTEXT2=5`(assume i enter 5 only );`EDITTEXT3=4995;` 
Still this everthing good. but i enter one more value in `EDITTEXT2=50`(5 is alredy there so i added 0 only.).now the result is `EDITTEXT3=4945`. but the answer we need **4950**. **The problem is 50 will be minus from old 4995 not from 5000**

Comment: add above listener to both edittext1 & edittext2 & not on edittext3.